# Is it Meaningful to Add 'x-frame-options' in an Restful API

Tags: rest, x-frame-options, clickjacking

We are developing a restful API that fulfils some various events. We have done a Nessus vulnerability scan to see security leaks. It turned out that we have some leaks leads to clickjacking and we have found the solution. I have added `x-frame-options` as `SAMEORIGIN`in order to handle problems.

My question here is that, since I am an API, do I need to handle clickjacking? I guess 3rd party user should be able to reach my API over an iframe and I don't need to handle this.

Do I miss something? Could you please share your ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit 2019-10-07:** @Taytay's [PR](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/pull/173) has been merged, so the OWASP recommendation now says that the server *should*  send an X-Frame-Options header.

---

**Original answer**:

[OWASP recommends](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Send_security_headers) that *clients* send an X-Frame-Options header, but makes no mention of the API itself.

I see no scenario where it makes any sense for the API to return clickjacking security headers - there is nothing to be clicked in an iframe!

Comment: I believe this is a typo because X-Frame-Options is a response header, not a client header. I've submitted a pull request to the OWASP cheatsheet repo to fix the recommendation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610943/x-frame-options-deny-is-not-wokring-for-spring-boot-rest-api?noredirect=1#comment105385341_59610943 
  ,@nickspoon, this is  a similar problem only. Can you please share your thoughts

Answer (score 16):

[OWASP recommends](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Security_headers) that not only do you send an X-Frame-Options header but that it is set to DENY.

These are recommendations not for a web site but for a REST service.

The scenario where it makes sense to do this is exactly the one the OP mentioned - running a vulnerability scan.

If you do not return a correct X-Frame-Options header the scan will fail. This matters when proving to customers that your endpoint is safe.

It is much easier to provide your customer a passing report than have to argue why a missing header does not matter.

Adding a X-Frame-Options header should not affect the endpoint consumer as it is not a browser with an iframe.

Comment: The linked article section says "Additionally the client should send an X-Frame-Options: deny". The _client_. Not the _server_.

Comment: @nickspoon I think there's a typo in the OWASP article since `X-Frame-Options` [is a response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

Comment: You're right. After your comment I tried contacting OWASP in various ways (before they moved to github) but never received any response. @Taytay has now successfully had the article updated so I've updated my answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610943/x-frame-options-deny-is-not-wokring-for-spring-boot-rest-api?noredirect=1#comment105385341_59610943   , @Stev. this is a similar problem. Can you please add your thoughts

Comment: Whilst undeniably sensible advice, this doesn't answer the OP's question about whether it is *meaningful* to provide this header in an API response.  It has no more meaning than an `X-Powered-By` header; the client will not take the slightest notice of it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the OWASP recommendation and reasons stated in the other answers, there are legitimate attacks that can be conducted against frameable API responses containing sensitive information. See: [GOTCHA: Taking phishing to a whole new level](https://medium.com/intigriti/gotcha-taking-phishing-to-a-whole-new-level-72eda9e30bef).

Essentially, the attack manipulates the sensitive information to deceive target users to disclose the information to the attacker. Therefore, whether *X-Frame-Options* or *Content-Security-Policy* (with the *frame-ancestors* directive), API responses should be restricted from being framed by arbitrary origins.